# AngularJS UI-router nested views with Apache Server

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess

i have an angularJS app using ui-router, here my config file content:

```
app
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {


if(window.history && window.history.pushState) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
}

$urlRouterProvider
.when('/', 'login')
.otherwise('/error404');

$stateProvider
.state({
    name: 'main',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: '/templates/navbar.html',
    controller : 'NavBarController',
})
.state({
    name: 'main.login',
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: '/templates/login.html',
    controller : 'LoginController as login',
    data: {
        authenticate: false,
        admin: false,
        navBar: false, 
    }
}); 

}]);
```

Also i have a .htaccess file containing:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

My folder structure is as below:

```
- www
 - mP
  - mPc
   -.htaccess
   -/js (containing all angularJS files)
   -/templates (containing all the template files)
   - index.html
```

And my index.html file has the following content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='App'>
<head>

<title>App</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/angularJS/dependencies/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/angularJS/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/angularJS/constants.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/angularJS/directives.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/angularJS/filters.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/angularJS/services.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/angularJS/controllers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/angularJS/config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/angularJS/run.js"></script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>

<body ng-controller='MainController'>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="center">

            <section ui-view></section>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When i try to access the site using localhost/mP/mPc/ it goes to localhost/error404 and when i use localhost/mP/mPc/login it shows an error saying "Not Found The requested URL /index.html was not found on this server"

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For login

```
$urlRouterProvider
.when('/', '/login')
```

Since you are using templates from same folder you can use relative path

```
templateUrl: 'templates/navbar.html',
```

Comment: thats not the problem

Comment: i checked and the .htaccess file is actually working and all the URL's are redirected to index.html but it seems that the UI-Router is detecting the URL differently because everything goes to the otherwise action. I tried putting a <base tag in the index file but isn't working. Any help??? Please!!!

Comment: Yes that's not the problem, I created similar code and folder structure. State routing was not working properly with requireBase=false; removed it and added base tag to index.html it is working properly. May be that version ui-router has issue, not sure needs to be checked.

Comment: Yeah did the same and also worked, but I had also to rename the root folder because i had two similar names for two projects and it was confusing them. E.g I had one called systemA and another one systemB and it was also causing the error. I hope it works for someone else. Thanks for your help tho.